# why there is no overflow in horners method in evaluating polynomial

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, polynomials

Evaluating polynomial

Basically I am calculating hash value of a string using following formula.

[image]

I am evaluating polynomial, and I am using naive method
A naive way to evaluate a polynomial is to one by one evaluate all terms. First calculate x^n, multiply the value with cn, repeat the same steps for other terms and return the sum. Using following algorithm

```
struct hashFunction {
    std::size_t operator() (const std::string& str) const {

        unsigned int uiHashValue     = 0;
        unsigned int uiPowerValueIdx = 0;
        std::uint64_t uiSum          = 0;
        for(unsigned int uiIdx = 0; uiIdx < str.length(); uiIdx++, uiPowerValueIdx++) {

            unsigned int uiCharAsciiVal = (str[uiIdx]);
            // calculate power of x ^ uiPowerValue
            std::uint64_t uiXToPowerValue     = 1;
            std::uint64_t uiIntermediateValue = uiXValue;
            unsigned int uiPowerValue        =  uiPowerValueIdx;
            std::cout << uiIdx << " char is " << str[uiIdx] << " ascii value " << uiCharAsciiVal ;
            while(uiPowerValue > 0) {
                // if power value is multiply x value with intermediate value
                if((uiPowerValue & 1) == 1) {
                    uiXToPowerValue = ((uiXToPowerValue % uiLargePrime) * (uiIntermediateValue %uiLargePrime)) %uiLargePrime ;
                }
                uiPowerValue = uiPowerValue >> 1;
                uiIntermediateValue = ((uiIntermediateValue % uiLargePrime) * (uiIntermediateValue % uiLargePrime)) % uiLargePrime;
            }
            std::cout << " power value " << uiXToPowerValue<< std::endl;
            uiSum = uiSum + (((uiCharAsciiVal % uiLargePrime )* (uiXToPowerValue % uiLargePrime)))%uiLargePrime;

        } // for loop

        std::cout << (uiSum % uiMValue) << std::endl;
        return uiSum % uiMValue;
    }
};
```

Now using horners method I am calcuating as below

```
struct hashFunctionNew {
    std::size_t operator() (const std::string& str) const {

        unsigned int uiHashValue     = 0;
        unsigned int uiPowerValueIdx = 0;
        std::uint64_t uiSum          = 0;
        std::uint64_t ans = 0;
        for( int uiIdx = str.length(); uiIdx >= 0; uiIdx--) {
            unsigned int uiCharAsciiVal = (str[uiIdx]);
             ans = (ans * uiXValue +uiCharAsciiVal) % uiLargePrime;
        }
        std::cout << "New function hash value: " << ans % uiMValue << std::endl;
        return ans % uiMValue;

    }
};
```

My questions are below

1. Why there is no overflow for Horners method though here also we calculate x^n, where as in naive method there is overflow. In both methods I am using mod operator to avoid overflow so in naive method also there should not be overflow.
2. My naive method is returning wrong hash value? I debugged but not sure why I am getting wrong value. For example hash value of "world" is 4 but naive method returns 1.  What is bug?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which won't cause a problem as long as the string is null-terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both your questions lies in this line:

```
uiSum = uiSum + (((uiCharAsciiVal % uiLargePrime )* (uiXToPowerValue % uiLargePrime)))%uiLargePrime;
```

This is where overflow is happening. You need to take modulus here as well.

```
uiSum = (uiSum + (((uiCharAsciiVal % uiLargePrime )* (uiXToPowerValue % uiLargePrime)))%uiLargePrime) % uiLargePrime;
```